# Why is the date of Pentecost calculated similar to the Saddusaical method?

Tags: law, calendar, christianity

From my (limited) understanding Christians are an offshoot of the Pharisaic traditions.

As explained in The Jewish Babylonian Talmud (and many other places..),
according to the Hazal, the Jewish rabbinic method of counting the omer and deciding the date of the Festival of Weeks is not connected to the days of the week.

How then did it happen that in the Christian tradition the counting is similar to the Sadducee method (Pentecost will always be a Sunday)?

Comment: Why do you say that "*Christians are an offshoot of the Pharisaic traditions*"?  It is Judaism that follows the Pharisaic traditions, not Christianity. Jesus and his followers were often criticized for *not* following the Pharisaic rules.

Comment: @RayButterworth exactly they where criticized becuse that was there "home base"  jesus himself was a pharasee no?

Comment: There are several ways to do these calculations with quite different results.  We do not know which method the Sadducees used.  Please quote a Bible verse to define the question.

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>15</sup> “You shall count seven full weeks from the day after the Sabbath, from the day that you brought the sheaf of the wave offering. <sup>16</sup> You shall count fifty days to the day after the seventh Sabbath. Then you shall present a grain offering of new grain to the LORD. (Leviticus 23 ESV)

If the instructions in Leviticus are followed, the day of Pentecost will always be observed on the day after the seventh Sabbath following the Feast of Fruits. If the Sabbath is Saturday, then Pentecost will always be observed on a Sunday.

Comment: yes I understand how it is understood fromthe bible 
my question is why do they differ from the jewish metho, that does not depend on the day of the week

Comment: @eliavs Shavout is always observed the day following a Sabbath. So it is always on the first day of the week.

Comment: @Revlation Lad In the Jewish rabinic tradition Shavout does *NOT* always on the first day of th week

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Because the Sadducee's calculation was in line with the scripture and the rabbinical was and still is wrong.

*15 ‘From the day after the Sabbath, the day you brought the sheaf of the wave offering, count off seven full weeks.
16 Count off fifty days up to the day after the seventh Sabbath, and then present an offering of new grain to the Lord.*
(Leviticus 23)

*14 ‘If you bring a grain offering of firstfruits to the Lord **(bikurim leJHVH)**, offer crushed heads of new grain roasted in the fire **(aviv qalui baesh)**.*
(Leviticus 2)

*10 On the evening of the fourteenth day of the month, while camped at Gilgal on the plains of Jericho, the Israelites celebrated the Passover.
11 The day after the Passover, that very day, they ate some of the produce of the land: unleavened bread and roasted grain **(qalui)**.
12 The manna stopped the day after they ate this food from the land; there was no longer any manna for the Israelites, but that year they ate the produce of Canaan.*
(Joshua 5)

In Joshua 5:11 the Israelites ate fresh roasted barley on the 15th of Nissan. It must have been the day of the first fruits of barley earlier on that day. The only way it could work was if the 14th was also a weekly sabbath. Summarizing, when rabbis say that the day after the sabbath of Leviticus 23 is the 16th of Nissan, they are 100% wrong. It is always Sunday.

Comment: A good answer, but it would be even better if there were some support for the fact that "*the rabbinical was and still is wrong*". Logically, saying one is right because the other is wrong is "begging the question".

Comment: @ארקדיוס 



1. sticking to the text does not seam too important to the christian tradition look at easter that is not in the middle of the month



2. I do not understand the logic of the proof from Joshua  "The only way it could work was if the 14th was also a weekly sabbath"